# Profiler Analysis for product list page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, pagespeed, profiler, speedoptimization

My product list page is very slow as I have customized things and use custom phtml for that, I have enabled the profiler and found this:

```
Memory usage: real: 78643200, emalloc: 49273704

Code Profiler   Time    Cnt Emalloc RealMem
mage    18.9151 1   0   0
mage::app::init::system_config  0.0012  1   27,520  0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Cache   0.0005  1   94,224  0
mage::app::init::config::load_cache 0.0164  1   1,784   0
mage::app::init::stores 0.0213  1   1,167,712   1,310,720
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website    0.0002  1   23,496  0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website_Collection 0.0110  1   488,808 524,288
DISPATCH EVENT:resource_get_tablename   0.0110  1100    56,272  0
DISPATCH EVENT:core_collection_abstract_load_after  0.0064  9   920 0
init_config_section:stores_default  0.0051  1   2,144   0
mage::app::init_front_controller    0.0119  1   243,976 0
mage::app::init_front_controller::collect_routers   0.0107  1   134,912 0
DISPATCH EVENT:controller_front_init_routers    0.0010  1   95,544  0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite_Request 0.0002  1   44,248  0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite 0.0008  47  27,032  0
mage::dispatch::db_url_rewrite  0.0074  1   45,872  0
DISPATCH EVENT:model_load_after 0.0072  251 12,504  0
DISPATCH EVENT:core_abstract_load_after 0.0004  60  3,352   0
mage::dispatch::routers_match   18.8396 1   0   0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::predispatch 0.2293  1   1,024,568   786,432
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Layout  0.0003  1   33,184  0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Session 0.0077  2   53,472  0
Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start/start    0.0017  1   10,528  0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::predispatch::load_area::frontend::design    0.0074  1   123,544 262,144
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package  0.0005  1   29,688  0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::predispatch::load_area::frontend::translate 0.0010  1   64,336  0
DISPATCH EVENT:controller_action_predispatch    0.2130  1   668,384 524,288
OBSERVER: clearandfizzy_enhancedcms_feed    0.0006  1   86,472  0
OBSERVER: ophirah_qquoteadv 0.0002  1   17,368  0
OBSERVER: log   0.2088  1   193,288 262,144
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Log_Model_Visitor  0.0044  1   36,616  0
OBSERVER: pagecache 0.0007  1   18,920  0
OBSERVER: persistent    0.0010  3   181,784 262,144
OBSERVER: persistent_quote  0.0006  1   130,320 0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Customer_Model_Session 0.0004  1   80,816  0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::catalog_category_view   18.6098 1   0   0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Catalog_Model_Category 0.0032  114 104,840 0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category    0.0045  1   96,984  262,144
EAV: Mage_Eav_Model_Config::getEntityType   0.0100  231 115,064 0
DISPATCH EVENT:model_load_before    0.0023  247 12,440  0
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_category_load_before 0.0020  112 5,848   0
__EAV_LOAD_MODEL__  4.2640  190 19,415,008  4,194,304
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Attribute_Collection   0.0013  2   48,328  262,144
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute   0.0012  140 92,352  0
EAV: Mage_Eav_Model_Config::getAttribute    0.0071  180 43,648  0
__EAV_LOAD_MODEL_ATTRIBUTES__   2.0602  190 18,576,912  524,288
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Default 0.0002  81  16,984  0
__EAV_LOAD_MODEL_AFTER_LOAD__   1.7099  190 5,359,920   2,097,152
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_category_load_after  0.0050  112 5,848   0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection 0.0012  3   27,896  0
__EAV_COLLECTION_BEFORE_LOAD__  0.0011  19  6,472   0
DISPATCH EVENT:eav_collection_abstract_load_before  0.0004  19  1,400   0
__EAV_COLLECTION_LOAD_ENT__ 1.2535  19  23,477,232  24,117,248
__EAV_COLLECTION_LOAD_ATTR__    1.1862  19  8,286,640   29,622,272
__EAV_COLLECTION_ORIG_DATA__    0.0118  19  1,128   0
__EAV_COLLECTION_AFTER_LOAD__   0.5069  19  6,504,168   524,288
DISPATCH EVENT:controller_action_layout_load_before 0.0011  1   10,880  0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::catalog_category_view::layout_load  0.1046  1   119,896 262,144
layout/package_update: default  0.0203  1   28,872  0
layout/db_update: default   18.5108 1   0   0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Layout 0.0002  12  6,144   0
layout/db_update: catalog_category_layered_nochildren   18.5044 1   0   0
layout/db_update: STORE_default 18.5012 1   0   0
layout/db_update: THEME_frontend_sterling_default   18.4961 1   0   0
layout/db_update: catalog_category_view 18.4929 1   0   0
layout/package_update: catalog_category_layered 0.0395  1   25,616  0
layout/db_update: SHORTCUT_popup    18.4834 1   0   0
layout/db_update: SHORTCUT_uk_popup 18.4703 1   0   0
layout/db_update: product_list  18.4602 1   0   0
layout/db_update: lot_lot_category  18.4530 1   0   0
layout/db_update: catalog_category_layered  18.4454 1   0   0
layout/db_update: CATEGORY_137  18.4368 1   0   0
layout/db_update: customer_logged_out   18.4329 1   0   0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::catalog_category_view::layout_generate_xml  0.0028  1   552 0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::catalog_category_view::layout_generate_blocks   0.4341  1   9,526,104   10,223,616
BLOCK: formkey  0.0015  1   261,448 262,144
DISPATCH EVENT:core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before    0.0012  137 7,080   0
DISPATCH EVENT:core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after 0.0356  137 140,224 1,048,576
OBSERVER: M2ePro_observer_view_order    0.0033  137 29,784  0
OBSERVER: M2ePro_observer_view_shipment_before  0.0053  137 18,872  0
OBSERVER: productedit   0.0099  137 24,672  0
OBSERVER: customercredit    0.0012  137 18,768  0
OBSERVER: sunarc_hidetab    0.0036  137 122,544 262,144
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Admin_Model_Session    0.0003  1   54,288  0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Admin_Model_Redirectpolicy 0.0001  1   47,624  0
DISPATCH EVENT:core_layout_block_create_after   0.0009  136 7,256   0
BLOCK: root 0.0088  1   72,304  0
BLOCK: head 0.0005  1   74,888  0
BLOCK ACTION: head -> addJs 0.0001  14  21,568  0
BLOCK: js_cookies   0.0005  1   68,032  262,144
BLOCK ACTION: head -> addItem   0.0006  21  38,112  0
BLOCK: head.viewport    0.0006  1   57,360  0
BLOCK: after_body_start 0.0004  1   57,440  0
BLOCK: global_notices   0.0078  1   66,368  0
BLOCK: header   0.0005  1   67,256  262,144
BLOCK: store_language   0.0005  1   69,672  0
BLOCK: catalog.topnav   0.0009  1   304,560 262,144
BLOCK: catalog.topnav.renderer  0.0007  1   181,120 262,144
BLOCK: top.container    0.0004  1   57,880  0
BLOCK: welcome  0.0004  1   65,520  0
BLOCK: breadcrumbs  0.0004  1   66,536  0
BLOCK: left_first   0.0034  1   1,312   262,144
BLOCK: global_messages  0.0007  1   82,752  0
BLOCK: footer   0.0006  1   102,360 0
BLOCK: global_cookie_notice 0.0004  1   66,216  262,144
BLOCK: core_profiler    0.0004  1   112,416 0
BLOCK: currency 0.0037  1   67,424  0
BLOCK: cms_footer_links 0.0006  1   58,120  262,144
BLOCK: catalog.compare.sidebar  0.0006  1   237,568 0
BLOCK: catalog_product_price_template   0.0004  1   57,192  262,144
BLOCK: checkout_cart_link   0.0004  1   65,848  0
BLOCK ACTION: checkout_cart_link -> addCheckoutLink 0.0003  1   19,600  0
BLOCK: minicart_head    0.0042  1   140,240 262,144
BLOCK: minicart_content 0.0005  1   77,568  0
BLOCK: paypal.partner.top_cart.shortcut 0.0006  1   155,208 0
BLOCK: right.poll   0.0006  1   115,048 0
BLOCK: right.reports.product.compared   0.0005  1   166,544 262,144
BLOCK: google_analytics 0.0004  1   70,600  0
BLOCK: wishlist_link    0.0029  1   140,856 0
BLOCK: wishlist_sidebar 0.0006  1   179,912 262,144
BLOCK: paypaluk.partner.top_cart.shortcut   0.0004  1   67,808  0
BLOCK: head_rss 0.0019  1   124,808 262,144
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Url 0.0052  247 146,664 0
BLOCK: footer.newsletter    0.0005  1   67,496  0
BLOCK: head.livechat.monitor    0.0004  1   65,384  0
BLOCK ACTION: header -> setTemplate 0.0044  1   38,792  262,144
BLOCK: miniquote_head   0.0006  1   152,312 0
BLOCK: qquoteadv_links  0.0004  1   66,272  0
BLOCK: quote_sidebar    0.0004  1   73,576  262,144
BLOCK ACTION: head -> addCss    0.0003  2   19,936  0
BLOCK:  0.0008  1   68,776  0
BLOCK: left.reports.product.viewed  0.0005  1   86,088  0
BLOCK: catalog.leftnav  0.3192  1   4,187,024   6,029,312
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection  0.0180  16  624,144 786,432
DISPATCH EVENT:core_abstract_load_before    0.0004  57  3,208   0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Index_Model_Lock_Storage_Db    0.0007  1   30,424  0
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_before  0.0004  40  2,440   0
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after   0.0004  40  2,696   0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Collection    0.0026  3   105,008 0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute_Option_Collection  0.0015  3   43,056  0
Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::getState  0.0001  1   23,744  0
BLOCK: catalog.leftnav.state.renderers  0.0014  1   1,800   0
BLOCK: category.products    0.0249  1   183,632 0
REWRITE: Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Url::getCategoryUrl    0.0326  7   60,160  0
BLOCK: product_list 0.0006  1   91,008  0
BLOCK: product_list_toolbar 0.0059  1   94,304  0
BLOCK: product_list_toolbar_pager   0.0008  1   89,272  0
BLOCK: paypal.partner.right.logo    0.0004  1   65,904  0
BLOCK: bml.center.logo  0.0052  1   67,248  0
BLOCK: configurableswatches.media.js.list   0.0009  1   135,968 0
BLOCK: category.info.lots   0.0005  1   66,160  0
BLOCK: sale.reorder.sidebar 0.0040  1   68,384  0
DISPATCH EVENT:controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after   0.0009  1   73,936  0
OBSERVER: configurableswatches  0.0092  158 98,752  0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::catalog_category_view::layout_render    17.9900 1   0   0
DISPATCH EVENT:core_block_abstract_to_html_before   0.0061  78  7,160   0
OBSERVER: qquoteadv_class_listener  0.0014  78  10,824  0
Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::getFilename 0.0056  60  66,984  0
frontend/sterling/default/template/page/1column.phtml   17.9887 1   0   0
frontend/sterling/default/template/page/html/head.phtml 0.0400  1   346,192 0
Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::getSkinUrl  0.0198  137 157,280 0
DISPATCH EVENT:core_block_abstract_to_html_after    0.0137  76  18,256  0
OBSERVER: M2ePro_observer_view_shipment_after   0.0018  76  17,240  0
OBSERVER: apptrian_minify_core_block_abstract_to_html_after 0.0014  76  25,456  0
frontend/base/default/template/directory/js/optional_zip_countries.phtml    0.0004  1   26,968  0
frontend/base/default/template/googleanalytics/ga.phtml 0.0006  1   19,560  0
frontend/sterling/default/template/qquoteadv/page/html/header.phtml 0.7145  1   2,927,056   3,145,728
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter   0.0006  6   86,816  0
frontend/sterling/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart.phtml 0.0096  1   63,480  262,144
frontend/sterling/default/template/webandpeople/custommenu/top.phtml    0.6426  1   2,312,672   2,621,440
frontend/sterling/default/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml    0.0020  2   47,960  0
frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml  17.2045 1   29,815,576  58,458,112
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_helper_output_construct  0.0004  1   21,144  0
OBSERVER: jvs_fileattribute 0.0003  1   18,096  0
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_block_product_list_collection    0.8719  1   17,649,664  18,350,080
OBSERVER: review    0.8716  1   17,645,296  18,350,080
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_collection_load_before   0.0002  16  1,504   0
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_collection_load_after    0.2589  8   6,194,032   262,144
OBSERVER: inventory 0.4556  86  4,353,792   262,144
OBSERVER: tax   0.0023  8   74,000  0
OBSERVER: bundle_observer   0.0121  8   80,416  0
frontend/sterling/default/template/qquoteadv/catalog/product/list.phtml 16.3058 1   29,806,776  46,137,344
EAV: Mage_Eav_Model_Config::_initAttributes 0.0115  2   934,320 786,432
CORE::create_object_of::Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Model_Catalog_Product   0.0108  80  68,680  0
locale/currency 0.0024  1   75,264  262,144
DISPATCH EVENT:currency_display_options_forming 0.0007  1   43,984  262,144
OBSERVER: mage_currencysymbol_currency_display_options  0.0006  1   41,072  262,144
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_is_salable_before    0.0048  438 21,512  0
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_is_salable_after 0.0040  438 21,512  0
_LOAD_ATTRIBUTE_BY_CODE__   0.0054  1   13,320  0
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_get_final_price  0.0638  39  115,992 0
OBSERVER: catalogrule   0.0613  39  119,736 0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule    0.0010  40  20,712  0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule 0.0012  39  28,312  0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url  0.0075  693 175,592 0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image    0.0004  39  22,360  0
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_load_before  0.0005  78  4,216   0
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_attribute_backend_media_load_gallery_before  0.0062  78  6,296   0
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_load_after   0.2378  78  -1,668,200  0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item  0.0011  39  69,688  0
OBSERVER: qquoteadv_set_allowed_to_quote    0.0041  78  38,432  0
init_config_section:stores_admin    0.0028  1   1,736   0
frontend/sterling/default/template/qquoteadv/catalog/product/c2qBtnList.phtml   1.3172  39  926,688 1,572,864
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options    0.0085  39  10,416  0
OBSERVER: payment_recurring_profile_prepare_options 0.0063  39  17,480  0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Configuration_Item_Option    0.0005  39  13,936  0
frontend/base/default/template/lot_lot/catalog/category/list/lot.phtml  0.0034  1   100,800 0
CORE::create_object_of::Lot_Lot_Model_Resource_Lot_Collection   0.0005  1   32,832  0
frontend/sterling/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml   0.0219  1   0   0
frontend/sterling/default/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml   0.0054  1   15,760  0
```

Can anyone help to analysis it what's going wrong

Comment: reference link = > https://www.nublue.co.uk/guides/speed-up-magento-profiler/

Comment: @SavanPatel, Thanks, I will check it.